# In C++, what does & mean after a function's return type?

Tags: c++

In a C++ function like this:

```
int& getNumber();
```

what does the `&` mean? Is it different from:

```
int getNumber();
```

Comment: The `&` basically states that I'm returning the **address** where the value returned is stored (i.e. it returns the `reference` of the integer) whereas the `int getNumber()` returns the `value` of the integer returned by the function.

One thing is that if the reference integer points to a NULL, you may have a segmentation fault whereas the other function returns a 0;

Comment: One thing that nobody's mentioned: never return a reference to a local variable! You'll get undefined results when the variable goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: As an aside, if `getNumber()` is a public method of a class that returns a private member variable of that class, don't use the version that returns a reference.  Otherwise, users of your class will be able to change the value of that private member outside the class.  In other words, the private member is no longer encapsulated by the class.

Comment: if & returns the address where the value returned is stored, how is that different from a pointer or returning a pointer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the `int&` version returns a reference to an `int`.  The `int` version returns an `int` by value.

See [the section on references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) in the C++ FAQ

Comment: Rather than make the OP read through a huge document that answers his question but only in a roundabout way, why not write a 10 line program that demonstrates the difference.

Answer (score 50):

It's different.

```
int g_test = 0;

int& getNumberReference()
{
     return g_test;
}

int getNumberValue()
{
     return g_test;
}

int main()
{
    int& n = getNumberReference();
    int m = getNumberValue();
    n = 10;
    cout << g_test << endl; // prints 10
    g_test = 0;
    m = 10;
    cout << g_test << endl; // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

the getNumberReference() returns a reference, under the hood it's like a pointer that points to an integer variable. Any change applyed to the reference applies to the returned variable.

The getNumberReference() is also a left-value, therefore it can be used like this:

```
getNumberReference() = 10;
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's different.

The & means you return a reference. Otherwise it will return a copy (well, sometimes the compiler optimizes it, but that's not the problem here).

An example is vector. The operator[] returns an &. This allows us to do:

```
my_vector[2] = 42;
```

That wouldn't work with a copy.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable example that doesn't use global variables!

@Johan, it wouldn't work because you'd be assigning to either a stack location or a copy of the location in the vector...

Comment: Well in pure C, variable[x] is the same as *(variable + x). So I assume, that by using vector.data()[x] works the same way, isn't itA?

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that without the `&` what you get back is a copy of the returned int, suitable for passing into other routines, comparing to stuff, or copying into your own variable.

With the `&`, what you get back is essentially *the variable containing* the returned integer. That means **you can actually put it on the left-hand side of an assignment**, like so:

```
getNumber() = 200;
```

Answer (score 4):

`int& getNumber()`: function returns an integer by reference.

`int getNumber()`: function returns an integer by value.

They differ in some ways and one of the interesting differences being that the 1st type can be used on the left side of assignment which is not possible with the 2nd type.

Example:

```
int global = 1;

int& getNumber() {
        return global; // return global by reference.
}

int main() {

        cout<<"before "<<global<<endl;
        getNumber() = 2; // assign 2 to the return value which is reference.
        cout<<"after "<<global<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Ouptput:

```
before 1
after 2
```

Answer (score 4):

The first version allows you to write `getNumber() = 42`, which is probably not what you want. Returning references is very useful when overloading `operator[]` for your own containers types. It enables you to write `container[9] = 42`.

Comment: Explain why it works for containers and you have a perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

"&" means reference, in this case "reference to an int".

Answer (score 3):

It means that it is a reference type. What's a reference?

Wikipedia:

> In the C++  programming language, a reference  is a simple reference datatype that is less powerful but safer than the pointer type inherited from C. The name C++ reference may cause confusion, as in computer science a reference is a general concept datatype, with pointers and C++ references being specific reference datatype implementations. The declaration of the form:
>
> Type & Name
>
> where  is a type and  is
>   an identifier whose type is reference
>   to .
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. int A = 5;
> 2. int& rA = A;
> 3. extern int& rB;
> 4. int& foo ();
> 5. void bar (int& rP);
> 6. class MyClass { int& m_b; /* ... */ };
> 7. int funcX() { return 42 ; }; int (&xFunc)() = funcX;
>
> Here, rA and rB are of type "reference
>   to int", foo() is a function that
>   returns a reference to int, bar() is a
>   function with a reference parameter,
>   which is reference to int, MyClass is
>   a class with a member which is
>   reference to int, funcX() is a
>   function that returns an int, xFunc()
>   is an alias for funcX.

Rest of the explanation is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29)

Comment: unfortunately wikipedia is wrong here.  It isn't safer than a pointer, it's exactly syntactic sugar for a const pointer (I do NOT mean pointer to const data).

Comment: But it can avoid a lot of compiler errors. This is what wikipedia means.

Comment: I've never heard of a single compiler error that was fundamentally different for pointers and references.

Comment: I found your answer helpful. Thanks. I do like the word 'safer' in the story. It helps me remember that it is more restricted in a certain sense and has 'less options', which is exactly what 'safer' means in many programming language related debates. A language that uses types as C++ is in a sense also 'safer' (= read has less freedom) than a language without types as PHP (= has more freedom). In a similar way a language that uses 'garbage' collection can is safer than one that doesn't, and there are many and many examples that demonstrate that the word safe in linked to less options.

Comment: As you can read above I find the use of the word 'safe' appropriate and I want to go even beyond this, I find using the word 'safe' here even superb. It is definetly not wrong as someone said above.

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference

Answer (score 1):

It means it's returning a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to an int, not an int itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference, which is exactly like a pointer except you don't have to use a pointer-dereference operator (* or ->) with it, the pointer dereferencing is implied.

Especially note that all the lifetime concerns (such as don't return a stack variable by address) still need to be addressed just as if a pointer was used.

Comment: References can be likened to pointers, and thought of as pointers but are definitely not "exactly like pointers". For example, assigning to a reference changes the value *referred to*, instead of the reference itself. Furthermore, references have to be assigned a value at the time of their creation, and keep referring to that same value throughout their lifetime.

Comment: @Thomas: References aren't assigned a value at creation, they're associated with an address -- a pointer.  Yes, they can't be reassociated with a new address, but neither can a const pointer.  Assignment via a reference is exactly the same as assignment via a pointer except that you need an extra asterisk for the pointer syntax, that's what I meant by "pointer dereferencing is implied".  A reference is no more and no less than a const pointer mixed with a little syntactic sugar.