# difference between "int & function(int, int)" and "int function (int, int)"

Tags: c++

```
int & function (int a, int b) //option 1 

int function (int a, int b) //option 2
```

What's the difference between "int & function(int, int)" and "int function (int, int)"? What exactly does "&" operator do in a function header?

Comment: It is part of the return type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379859/in-c-what-does-mean-after-a-functions-return-type

Comment: @Brian Thanks.  I was out of close votes.