# Clarification of char&

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I have just started C++ coding and doing a question on `string`s. I have come across a function to find a particular character in a `string`, `char& at(size_t pos)`. I understood the functionality of the function but I am unable to understand what does `char&` signifies.

Can anybody explain this doubt.

Comment: This is C++ reference. I suggest reading about C++ references in general and in some depth. They're quite important to using the language effectively.

Comment: You can also read about references in your most hated C++ book if you want. Just make sure it is a good book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, what does & mean after a function's return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379859/in-c-what-does-mean-after-a-functions-return-type)

Answer (score 1):

`char &` means that the function returns a reference to the specific character at position `pos` in the `string`. This function is the same than doing `string[pos]` which you can use to read or modify the `char` at position `pos`. The difference is that  the `at` function will throw an exception if `pos` is bigger than the `string`'s size.

`at()` function exists with another variant: `const char & at(size_t pos) const`: which reports a `const` reference on the character (you cannot modify it and hence you ensure nothing will happen to the original string).